# Return wordpress post featured images using Fishpig in Magento

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, wordpress-featured-image, fishpig

Im trying to get two of the latest posts from Wordpress that include featured images. Need to get the post title, content (character limited) and the featured image. I have this so far, all that is missing is the featured image.

```
<div class="block block-blog block-recent-posts">
    <?php $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
              $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
              $query = "SELECT `id`, `post_title`,`post_name` ,`post_content`, `comment_count` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type`='post' ORDER BY `comment_count` DESC LIMIT 10";
              $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
    ?>
        <ul>

            <?php 
    $counter = 0; 
    foreach($results as $row) { ?>

          <?php if($row['post_title']!='Auto Draft'):   ?>
            <li class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('news/').$row['post_name'];?>"> <?php echo $row['post_title'];?></a>
                <p class="blog-content">  <?php $content = $row['post_content'];  echo $string = substr($content,0,220); if(strlen($content)>220){echo "...";}      ?></a></p>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
<?php

         if($counter == 2)
         {
              break;
         }
         $counter++;   
    }

    ?>


        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I have updated your query and added another query to get post image url :

```
<div class="block block-blog block-recent-posts">
    <?php $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
              $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
              $query = "SELECT p.id,p.post_title,p.post_name ,p.post_content,p.comment_count,pm.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta AS pm INNER JOIN wp_posts AS p ON pm.post_id=p.ID WHERE pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' AND p.post_type='post' ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 10";
              $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
    ?>
        <ul>

            <?php 
    $counter = 0; 
    foreach($results as $row) { ?>

          <?php if($row['post_title']!='Auto Draft'):   
              //Get url from pm.meta_value
              /********/
              $readConnection1 = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
              $query1 ="SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = '".$row['meta_value']."' AND meta_key='_wp_attached_file'"; 
              $results1 = $readConnection->fetchAll($query1);
              $url='www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/'.($results1[0]['meta_value']);
              echo $url; //YOUR URL just set your site name  
//So final url YOUR--> SITENAME/wp-content/uploads/pathfromquery 

              ?>
            <li class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('news/').$row['post_name'];?>"> <?php echo $row['post_title'];?></a>
                <p class="blog-content">  <?php $content = $row['post_content'];  echo $string = substr($content,0,220); if(strlen($content)>220){echo "...";}      ?></a></p>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
<?php

         if($counter == 2)
         {
              break;
         }
         $counter++;   
    }

    ?>


        </ul>
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [meta_id] => 24 [post_id] => 14 [meta_key] => _wp_attached_file [meta_value] => 2016/05/image.jpg ) )     and then the title and content.    Thats what I'm getting now.

Comment: ah didn't notice. yeah ther url is in there so I can work with that. Thanks!

Comment: if you get solution please make my answer as solution by ticked (clicked) right beside my answer and upvote..thx :)

Comment: not there yet, can't just extract that url. any ideas?

Comment: remove print_r and add $url='www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/'.($results1[0]['meta_value']);
              echo $url;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109989/discussion-between-vrajesh-and-jord49).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be using raw SQL here. As a work around, couldn't you do either of the following:

1) Select more than 2 posts (eg. 5) and loop through them and display the 2 that have featured images

2) Ensure all posts have featured images and then select the first 2 posts

3) Use a collection of posts and then add your custom SQL to that.

This code will get 2 posts and add the _thumbnail_id to the collection. You can add some code to this to check this field exists (use $posts->load(true) to debug the SQL query and $posts->getSelect()->where() to add the custom filter)

```
<?php $posts = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection') ?>
<?php $posts->addPostTypeFilter('post') ?>
<?php $posts->addIsViewableFilter() ?>
<?php // Limit the collection to 2 posts. Change this number or remove this line completely to include all posts
<?php $posts->setPageSize(2) ?>
<?php // Adds the _thumbnail_id meta field to the collection ?>
<?php // This can be used for checking in the SQL whether a post has a featured image ?>
<?php $posts->addMetaFieldToSelect('_thumbnail_id') ?>
<?php $posts->load() ?>
<?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
            <li>
                <h2><a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>"><?php echo $post->getPostTitle() ?></a></h2>
                <?php if ($image = $post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>" class="img"><img src="<?php echo $image->getAvailableImage() ?>" alt="" /></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="post-content"><?php echo $post->getPostContent() ?></div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Could you paste in something I can try using that to return all posts? I can configure the loop to return X amount of posts but not sure what I'm doing with this really. Thanks

Comment: The setPageSize method limits the collection to 2 posts. To return all posts, simply remove this line. You can also remove the addMetaFieldToSelect method if you don't want to check for featured images. You can then call $post->getFeaturedImage() to get the featured image. I have updated the code slightly in my answer.