# Fishpig get last 3 blog posts

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, fishpig

Can anyone supply me with some code that will grab the last 3 blog posts from Wordpress within Magento using the Fishpig extension. Can't find a template to use anywhere. Need to grab blog title, content and featured image.

I believe i'm on the wrong track with what I have so far.

```
<?php $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
   $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
   $query = "SELECT p.id,p.post_title,p.post_name ,p.post_content,p.comment_count,pm.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta AS pm INNER JOIN wp_posts AS p ON pm.post_id=p.ID  ORDER BY p.post_date";
   $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);


   ?>
<?php 
   foreach($results as $row) { ?>
<?php if($row['post_title']!='Auto Draft'):  
   //Get url from pm.meta_value
   /********/
   $readConnection1 = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
   $query1 ="SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = '".$row['meta_value']."' AND meta_key='_wp_attached_file'"; 
   $results1 = $readConnection->fetchAll($query1);
   $url='/news/wp-content/uploads/'.($results1[0]['meta_value']);
   ?>
<div class="blog-post-image">
   <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>">
</div>
<div class="blog-post-content">
   <?php  ?>
   <h3> <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('news/').$row['post_name'];?>"> <?php echo $row['post_title'];?></a></h3>
   <p class="blog-content">  <?php $content = $row['post_content'];  echo $string = substr($content,0,220); if(strlen($content)>220){echo "...";}      ?></a></p>
   <a href="" class="blog-posts-cta">More Info</a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
   if($counter == 4)
   {
        break;
   }
   $counter++;   
   }


?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: SO is a site that helps other developers with coding issues, however we won't just do the work for you. If you are having troubles, perhaps you could post the code you have attempted so far.

Comment: I've posted another post relating to this, but it went on a bit of a tangent. It appeared that I was also going down the wrong route with it, so am open to new suggestions.

Comment: have edited my OP and added my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return wordpress post featured images using Fishpig in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793336/return-wordpress-post-featured-images-using-fishpig-in-magento)